# Установил библиотеку SimpleQiwi, но получаю ошибки при запуске

Tags: python, json

Я установил  библиотеку SimpleQiwi, но Python ругается при запуске, при этом ошибок в моем коде он не находит. Я даже создал отдельный python-документ, в котором просто скопировал нужный мне код из документации и настроил под себя, но все равно получаю море ошибок:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 257, in _async_loop
    target()
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 263, in _parse_payments
    payments = self.payments
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 60, in payments
    return self._get_payments()
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 164, in _get_payments
    data = response.json()
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Что можно сделать?

Comment: Библиотека ожидает, что придёт `json`, а там `None` возвращается. Без кода это только гадать почему.

Comment: @CrazyElf т.е. мне предоставить 355 лайн, где библиотека ожидает, что придет ```json``` или предоставить мой фрагмент кода?

Comment: Я не знаю, что вам делать, я написал всё, что можно понять из ошибки. Попробуйте через `Fiddler` посмотреть, какой запрос отправляется и какой ответ приходит. Может что-то понятнее станет.